# Styling QR Code Generated with simple-QRcode in Laravel to Achieve Circular Eye Shape

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm using the **`simple-QRcode`** package in Laravel to generate QR codes, and I'm trying to style the QR code to have a circular eye shape instead of the default square eye. However, I'm facing an issue where the eyeball shape remains square even though I've managed to change the eye to a circular shape.

Here's the code I'm using to generate and style the QR code:

```
 QrCode::size(200)
        ->eye('circle')
        ->style('round')
        ->format('png')
        ->generate('Example', public_path('test.png'));
```

Achieved QR Code

[image]

want to achieve QR code like this

[image]

Comment: With simple-QRcode is not possible i have used this package for qr generation. this style not available

Comment: did you get that result using some other packages?

Comment: check this package hope will work for you. https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode